# Method Channel Flutter (android native)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

```
`package com.testmrthodcn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    public static final String CHANNEL = "com.itcat.humanos/sasigarn";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine){
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        System.out.println("flutter print :: configureFlutterEngine222");


        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                            System.out.println("flutter print :: result");

                        if (call.method.equals("getNativeData")) {
                            System.out.println("flutter print :: if configureFlutterEngine");
                            String data = "55555555 from native"; // ทำงานกับข้อมูลจาก Android
                            result.success(data);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("flutter print :: else    configureFlutterEngine");
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
            );

    System.out.println("flutter print :: after MethodChannel");

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this.getFlutterEngine());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(
                    FlutterActivity
                            .withNewEngine()
                            .initialRoute("/test_methodchannel")
                            .build(MainActivity.this)
            );
        }

    });

    }
}`

`import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestMethodchannel extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TestMethodchannel createState() => _TestMethodchannel();
}


class _TestMethodchannel extends State<TestMethodchannel> {

  static const channel = const MethodChannel('com.itcat.humanos/sasigarn');
  String _dataFromNative = 'No Data';

  Future<void> _getNativeData() async {

String? data;
try {
  final String? result = await channel.invokeMethod<String>('getNativeData', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});
  data = result;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  data = "Failed to get data: '${e.message}'.";
}


print('flutter data : '+data.toString());

setState(() {
  _dataFromNative = data.toString();
});

 }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Native Data Fetcher'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _getNativeData,
          child: Text('Fetch Data from Native'),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        Text('Data from Native: $_dataFromNative'),
      ],
    ),
    ),
  );
 }
}`
```

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> getNativeData on channel com.itcat.humanos/sasigarn)
> #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)

I've tried almost every code mod. But still unable to send value.
I tried cleaning flutter and it still doesn't work.

Comment: could you please share the native code you wrote in java/kotlin? and are you sure that you have followed the instructions exactly as mentioned [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation)?

Comment: environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

Flutter version 3.13.0